# Combine a 2D array with a scanner and an if-statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have an array like:

```java
int[][] gamefield = new int[4][4];

gamefield[0][0] = 1;
gamefield[0][1] = 2;
gamefield[0][2] = 3;
gamefield[0][3] = 4;
// and so on...
```

And a `coordinate()` method:

```
static void coordinate(int[][] gamefield) {
    int row= 0;
    int column= 0;

    Scanner entry= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\n\nEnter a number to move");

    System.out.print("row: ");
    row = entry.nextInt();

    System.out.print("column: ");
    column = entry.nextInt();
}
```

I want to replace an element with an `if` statement or something else. How can I do that?

```java
if (entry.equals(gamefield[0][0])) {
    gamefield[0][0] = 2;
}
```

So if the user types for row 0 and for column 0, the element in the array in the position [0][0] should be 2 and not 1.

**Context**

I have an 2D-Array, which has 4*4 elements. So from gamefield [0][0]to gamefield[4][4]. There is also an input for choosing the row and the column, the user can input his answer.

I just want to edit the numbers in the table. If in the first row is a 1, and in the second row is a 2, so I want to make clear, that for example if the user puts 1 to row scanner and 1 to column scanner, the number 2 should move to the position where 1 is and the 2 should have the position where 1 is. So kinda replacing it, just think in a 4*4 table, where the numbers can move in there. 
I am trying to built a 15 puzzle game, also called slider. But I can't solve my problem, I can't change or move the elements in the table.

Comment: Your question is not much clear,Tell us clearly what your code wants to do.

Comment: u cant compare scanner like that, compare the values of `row` or `column`

Comment: @AmitNandal Hey I'am sorry for my unclear question. I added some more information in my question, I hope, that you can help me.

Comment: @ashishsingh Thanks for your replying, but I really dont have any idea how to do that. Can you give me an example? I would really appreciate it and thanks for your replying.